# strip_tags not working in this example

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I cant make strip_tags works, i have really tried to change position, syntax, i usually make it work, but here is not working. why?

```
<?PHP 
$sum_string = $row_lastitem['summary'];
$sum_string = strip_tags($sum_string);
$sum_string = (strlen($sum_string) > 255) ? substr($sum_string,0,252).'...' : $sum_string;

$sum_string = nl2br($sum_string);

echo $sum_string; ?>
```

The html is there: like

```
<p>this is a example</p>
<p>line 2 </p>
```

Can someone point at my error pls.

Even this wont work

```
<?PHP 
    $sum_string = $row_lastitem['summary'];
    $sum_string = strip_tags($sum_string);

    echo $sum_string; ?>
```

Comment: What is the original value of `$row_lastitem['summary']`? Maybe it contains entities like `$lt;` instead of `<`?

Comment: The original Value is there in the question , copied and pasted from database <p>this is a example</p>
<p>line 2 </p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solution :

Sorry just found in related. 
[Why doesn't strip_tags work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780888/why-doesnt-strip-tags-work-in-php?rq=1)

html_entity_decode needed. thanks

```
<?PHP 
$sum_string = $row_lastitem['summary'];


$sum_string = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($sum_string)); ;
$sum_string = (strlen($sum_string) > 255) ? substr($sum_string,0,252).'...' : $sum_string;

$sum_string = nl2br($sum_string);

echo $sum_string; ?>
```

Comment: if that's needed, it means my comment was right: your database contains entities, not the raw HTML characters.

Comment: This means the code that inserts into the database is calling `htmlentities()`. This is usually poor design -- that should be used when displaying, not when storing.